# Ruby use collect/map with an attribute of a table

Tags: ruby, dictionary, collect

I have students who took  'tests', which have 5 'questions'. What I want to do is to show the max 'score' for each question for each test.

Test, Student, Question are all separate table.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :students
end
```

The code that I have:

```
<% @tests.each do |test| %>
<% max_score = [] %>
    <% test.students.collect {|s| s.questions.collect {|q| max_score << q.score}}%>

    <tr>
      <th><%= test.name %></th>
      <th><%= max_score.max %></th
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

However, what this shows is the max score for the whole test.

example)

```
Math - 95
History - 98
Physics - 100
```

It does not return the max for each 'question_number' 1 to 5. I want to print the max score for each question for each test.

example)

```
Math - 1 - 90
Math - 2 - 100
Math - 3 - 88
Math - 4 - 79
Math - 5 - 98
History - 1 - 80
History - 2 - 95
..and so on...
```

In the Question table it has a column named 'question_number'. I don't know how to use this attribute to get the result I want.

Comment: It seems to me you want an other loop and traverse over all questions objects outputting the number of the question and the score attribute. The way you describe it now you don't really want to use the max method at all.

Comment: Check my answer. Note also that you got the collect completely wrong, it's not supposed to be used imperatively (search for 'functional ruby' in google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as your comment suggests, you're unable to alter your class structure then it's going to be a bit ugly. You can still add `has_many :through` to clean things up a little bit:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  has_many :questions, :through => :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :students
end
```

then you're going to have to nest iterators...

```
<% @tests.each do |test| %>
  <% 1.upto(5) do |index|
    max = test.questions.select {|q| 
            q.question_number == index }.max_by {|q| q.score } %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= test.name %></td>
      <td><%= index %></td>
      <td><%= max.score %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

One issue with your code as it stands is that you're only outputting a `<tr>` once for each test. You want to do it once for each question. A better solution would be to write scopes. Something along the lines of:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  has_many :questions, :through => :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student

  scope :max_score_by_question_number, lambda {|num| where(:question_number => num).maximum(:score) }
end
```

Then you could do this, which looks nicer

```
<% @tests.each do |test| %>
  <% 1.upto(5) do |index|
    max = test.questions.max_score_by_question_number(index) %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= test.name %></td>
        <td><%= index %></td>
        <td><%= max.score %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have your models wrong. Play with this:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :question_scores
  has_many :students, :through => :question_scores
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_scores
  has_many :questions, :through => :question_scores
end

class QuestionScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :question
end
```

And the code should be something like this:

```
<% @tests.each do |test| %>
  <% test.questions.each do |question| %>
    test: <% test.name %>
    question: <%= question.name %>
    max score: <%= question.question_scores.maximum(:score) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see how it could be changed and it makes more sense. However, there is no way to change the structure at the moment.